# why surfaceCreated and surfaceDestroyed called several times when set visibility with GONE and continue with VISIBLE?

Tags: android, surfaceview

i found that this codes will cause surfaceCreated and surfaceDestroyed to be called several times:

```
mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

could anybody tell me why surfaceCreated and surfaceDestroyed doesn't to be called only once ?

Answer (score 4):

If you implement `SurfaceHolder.Callback` and put a logger inside each of `surfaceDestroyed`, `surfaceCreated`, `surfaceChanged` methods, you will see that those two lines will generate the following output:

```
04-01 12:50:54.688: INFO/app(4842): SurfaceView destroyed!
04-01 12:50:54.688: INFO/app(4842): SurfaceView created!
04-01 12:50:54.718: INFO/app(4842): SurfaceView changed!
```

Using two breakpoints before and after the calls to `setVisibility`, just make sure you don't count other logs.

Comment: infact,those two lines are called in onStartCommand method of a service,i have add breakpoint,and found surfaceDestroyed will enter two or more times

Comment: So your service has a side effect on your activity and cause it get refreshed (resumed, paused ...) and its consequences is surface destruction. Please add complete code of service and surface view.