# Do I save battery if I set CameraPreview visibility to GONE?

Tags: android, android-camera, batterylevel

I have a simple class called `CameraPreview`, this is the code:

```
    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {}

        try {
            SurfaceHolder someHolder = holder;
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(someHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null)
            return;

        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){}

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){}
    }
}
```

It's obvious that, while the application is showing the `CameraPreview` on screen, it will consume battery faster, my question is,what will happen to the battery if I set this view to `View.GONE`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15743933/2271834) setting the SurfaceView visbility to `GONE` will call `surfaceDestroyed` method.

Therefore, since you are stopping the camera, you won't consume user's battery.